# Browser.evaluate() method showing error

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, swt

I have written a simple Java program using the SWT API. I have instantiated a browser in the app and trying to use the `browser.evaluate()` method . But It shows me the following error

The method `evaluate(String)` is undefined for the type Browser

Here is my complete programe

```
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWTError;
    import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder;
    import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
    import org.eclipse.swt.browser.*;
    import org.eclipse.swt.printing.*;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;



    public class example {

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell=new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Informatica Business Glossary Desktop");

        final Browser browser = new Browser(shell,SWT.NONE);

        final String SCRIPT01 = "var html = \"\";"+
                "if (typeof window.getSelection != \"undefined\") {"+
                    "var sel = window.getSelection();"+
                    "if (sel.rangeCount) {"+
                        "var container = document.createElement(\"div\");"+
                        "for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {"+
                            "container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());"+
                        "}"+
                        "html = container.innerHTML;"+
                    "}"+
                "} else if (typeof document.selection != \"undefined\") {"+
                    "if (document.selection.type == \"Text\") {"+
                        "html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;"+
                    "}" +
                "}" +
                "return html";
        //final Browser browser;


    if(browser!=null)
{

    browser.setUrl("https://www.google.com");
}

        browser.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            @Override
            public void mouseDoubleClick(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent e) {
                String selection = (String)browser .evaluate(SCRIPT01);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDown(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseUp(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent e) {
                String selection = (String) browser.evaluate(SCRIPT01);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }



        });
     }  
    }
```

Error is shown at

```
String selection = (String) browser.evaluate(SCRIPT01);
```

I am using Eclipse Juno

Comment: I don't get any error.

Comment: Then why am only i getting it?

Comment: According to the JavaDoc `evaluate` was not in early versions of `Browser` check you have a recent version of the SWT jars

Comment: To be specific, you'll need SWT 3.5 or above (4.4 is the current version).

Comment: I have downloaded the jar file from here http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.1-201009090800/index.php#SWT  Isnt this the latest?

Comment: You'll find the latest release [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/#SWT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDoc for the `evaluate` method of the `Browser` class says it was added for SWT version 3.5 so you need to have at least that version.

The latest version for Eclipse Luna is [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/#SWT)